# How to insert/add an object to object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I thought the below is logically sound in adding or inserting object into an object array but the result I am getting is funky. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?? Why is below code returning empty array when I am trying to insert an object into an object array in the index of 0 and why is below code returning 4 when I am trying to add an object at the end of the object array?

```js
let objArr = [{
    id: 1,
    company: "Rapid Precision Mfg.",
    title: "Quality Engineer",
    firstName: "Dongyob",
    lastName: "Lee",
    officePh: "",
    ext: "",
    cell: "669-294-0910",
    email: "dyl4810@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Facebook",
    title: "Frontend Developer",
    firstName: "Edward",
    lastName: "Simmons",
    officePh: "408-516-4662",
    ext: "003",
    cell: "669-252-4251",
    email: "edwardsimmons@gmail.com"
  }
]
let nobj = {
  id: 1,
  company: "Rapid Precision Mfg.",
  title: "Quality Engineer",
  firstName: "Dongyob",
  lastName: "Lee",
  officePh: "",
  ext: "",
  cell: "669-294-0910",
  email: "dyl4810@gmail.com"
}
console.log(objArr.splice(0, 0, nobj)) //Outcome: []
console.log(objArr.push(nobj)) //Outcome: 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`splice` returns the *removed elements* of the array. If you don't remove any elements in the `splice` call, the returned array will be empty.

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
// from index 0, don't remove any elements, and insert element 'foo':
console.log(arr.splice(0, 0, 'foo'));
```

`push` returns the *new length* of the array. The output is 4 because the array started with 2 items, you `splice`d one item in (making the length 3), then `push`ed another item in, making the length 4.

Your current code

```
console.log(objArr.splice(0, 0, nobj))
console.log(objArr.push(nobj))
```

is inserting `nobj` into the last position *and* into the first position in the array - if you want to see what the array is afterwards, log the array:

```
console.log(objArr);
```

Note that rather than `splice`ing in an element at index 0, you can use `unshift` instead:

```js
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];
arr.unshift('foo');
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you so much all I needed to do is console.log(objArr), I am an idiot!

Answer (score 0):

The splice syntax is `array.splice(index, howmany, item1, ....., itemX)` and it returns the `removed` one.

If you want to test your change do `console.log(objArr)`

```js
let objArr = [{
    id: 1,
    company: "Rapid Precision Mfg.",
    title: "Quality Engineer",
    firstName: "Dongyob",
    lastName: "Lee",
    officePh: "",
    ext: "",
    cell: "669-294-0910",
    email: "dyl4810@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    company: "Facebook",
    title: "Frontend Developer",
    firstName: "Edward",
    lastName: "Simmons",
    officePh: "408-516-4662",
    ext: "003",
    cell: "669-252-4251",
    email: "edwardsimmons@gmail.com"
  }
]
let nobj = {
  id: 1,
  company: "Rapid Precision Mfg.",
  title: "Quality Engineer",
  firstName: "Dongyob",
  lastName: "Lee",
  officePh: "",
  ext: "",
  cell: "669-294-0910",
  email: "dyl4810@gmail.com"
}
objArr.splice(0, 0, nobj)
console.log(objArr) //Outcome: []
//console.log(objArr.push(nobj))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You answer helped but unfortunately, I chose the first person who responded. Thanks!

Comment: @LeeDongyobEric thats ok no problem

Answer (score 0):

As the above users have mentioned, `splice()` returns the removed element(s) of the array. If you are trying to push an object to the start of your array, another way to do so would be to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (yay ES6!!). I think it is much more readable than the method you are trying to employ.

```
//[nobj, ...objArr]
console.log([nobj, ...objArr]);
```

Unlike unshift(), it does not modify the original `objArr` array in-place.

```
const newArray = [nobj, ...objArr];
```

Comment: This is very useful, an immutable way to add an object to array.

Comment: Yup! Good concept to remember, especially if you are dealing a lot with React/Redux!